# Is the stack grown only when entering a function?

Tags: c

In C, one can declare variables inside blocks. Is the space for variables declared inside these blocks allocated (i.e. the stack expands) when entering the function, or only later, when entering the block?

I know I could answer the question by firing up a debugger and looking at the disassembly, but I'm interested in knowing if the behavior is consistent across different platforms/compilers, and whether it can change as a result of optimizations.

EDIT: The answer is "it's implementation defined". It seems most implementation would indeed only do it when entering the function, excepted for dynamic-size arrays and `alloca()`. See the comments of this question and of the accepted answer for more details.

Comment: "but I'm interested in knowing if the behavior is consistent across different platforms/compilers" - Seeing as C, the language, has no notion of a "stack", nothing is guaranteed.  Of course, most implementations will take the most sensible route for something like this.  BTW, the stack doesn't actually "expand". It is a pre-allocated block.

Comment: The stack memory space is allocated when the code is built (linkage-phase, to be more accurate), according to the linker-settings in your project configuration. So the total size of the stack is constant throughout the execution of the program, and in fact - throughout **every** execution of the program (unless you change it in your project's linker settings and rebuild the code).

Comment: @EdS.: `the stack doesn't actually "expand"` - in some sense it does: for native Windows clients at least, memory space for the stack is reserved up front but only committed as needed.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: And hence the "it depends" part of my answer :).  Even I fell into the trap.

Comment: Well, even though stack space is limited, there is a difference. Consider a function that calls another function, then executes a block. If the space for the block variable is reserved (that seems a better term than "allocated") when the function is entered, it will reduce the stack space the called function can use; otherwise not.

Comment: @Ed S. Not sure what you consider the obvious good solution. Reserving upon entering the function is more efficient, but I don't think that reserving space for a big stack-allocated structure that is not going to be used is a good idea: if you do some consequent (but finite) amount of recursion, it can drastically reduce the possible recursion depth if the structure is not used in the recursive path.

Comment: @Norswap: More efficient than allocating, say, 1MB up front and never asking for more again? More efficient than incrementing/decrementing a pointer to reserve space when needed?  How so?

Comment: @EdS. I'm not sure I get what you are asking. I was saying that reserving space (incrementing the pointers that points to the top of the stack) only once when entering the function is more efficient than incrementing it every time a block with some variables in it is entered.

Comment: @Norswap: I think I was confused with your previous use of the term "allocate".  You say "reserve" in the last couple of comments, so I see what you're getting at now.  IIRC, the total space needed is going to be reserved up front.  Sure, you may move the pointer a bit further than it needs to given conditional allocation (i.e., you're automatic variables in a block), but it also means only one pointer increment. That said, I'm not 100% sure about common implementations as it's been a long time since I've thought about it.  Of course, with optimizations in play, many things may happen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the perspective of the C programming language, all that's guaranteed is that variables with automatic storage duration (local variables) will have their memory created and destroyed as appropriate when the program is run. To the best of my knowledge, it's completely implementation defined if and when the memory for each variable will be allocated and deallocated.

In the extreme, variables might not even get memory assigned to them if they're local variables that can be stored inside registers. In that case, many different variables might actually have the same location in memory even though technically speaking they all exist at the same time, provided that the compiler could notice that the variables never actually need to co-exist. At another extreme, space for variable-length arrays can't be allocated until the size is known, so unless the compiler can do static analysis and determine that the memory for the array is needed earlier on it probably has to defer allocation until the point where the VLA is declared.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Good point about the VLAs, that's also true for `alloca()`. But more than standard guarantees, I'd be interested to know what is done "usually in practice", assuming there is a need to actually assign a memory location to a variable.

Comment: @Norswap It is a valid approach for a compiler to grow the stack upon every block that it enters, and shrink it back again when the block is left. That's exactly one addition and one subtraction on the stack pointer for each block, so it's not too bad. However, this is not needed except for the two cases mentioned already (VLAs and `alloca()`), in all other cases, the total size for a stack frame can be computed statically. As such, most compilers will try to avoid the overhead of changing stack size for the sake of some very short loops that contain little more than a single instruction.

Comment: Fair enough! However do see my comment under the question to see why it might be a bad thing reserve space when entering the function (essentially, it can reduce possible recursion depth).

Comment: @norswap: That might be a bad thing, but you did not ask "what is the best way a compiler might handle...", which is just as well because that would be considered opinion-seeking which is out-of-scope. cmaster's comment about what most compilers do certainly corresponds to what I've seen compilers do -- although I can't claim to be familiar with "most" compilers; I've only really ever looked at three of them. Yes, it is sometimes problematic. C'est la vie.

Comment: Yes, I'm not contesting that he answered my question, just pointing out a potential pitfall in the explanation he gave; as he justifies the compiler behavior by the gains it incurs, but does not mention any trade-off.